# Click on Radio Button from Android App to a Html Page

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have an html code like

```
 <TR>
               <TD VALIGN="TOP" ALIGN="LEFT" CLASS="d">
<!--                  <INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="causeA" CHECKED>Cause List A -->
                  <BR><INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="causeB"  CHECKED>Cause List
                  <!--<BR><INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="advcause">Advance List-->
                  <BR><INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="fresh">Fresh List
                  <BR><INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="additional">Additional
                  <BR><INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="backlog">Backlog Fresh
                  <BR><INPUT  STYLE="margin-left: 64pt"TYPE="RADIO" NAME="type" VALUE="supplementary">Supplementary Fresh
               </TD>
            </TR>
```

I want open this page in webview and click on these buttons from app normal buttons.

I know i have to use javascript interface.But not getting any idea how to do here

Regards
Mobic

Answer (score 0):

```
// Enablejavascript
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// Add the interface to record javascript events
wv.addJavascriptInterface(valid, "valid");
wv.addJavascriptInterface(refuse, "refuse");
```

Here, valid and refuse is the id of the buttons in the website. and declare those buttons as such...

```
valid = new Button(ctx);
valid.setOnClickListener(this);
refuse = new Button(ctx);
refuse.setOnClickListener(this)
```

And finally, handle the click events in the onClick method :

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.equals(valid)) {
    //do Something
} else if (v.equals(refuse)) {
    //do Something else }
}
```

Hope this will help.. Cheers!